# withRouter HOC and getDerivedStateFromProps

Tags: reactjs, react-16

I am trying to use `getDerivedStateFromProps` in a component as follows:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            location: '',
        };
    }

    static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
        return {
            location: nextProps.location.pathname,
        };
    }

    render() {....}
}

const EnhancedComponent = withRouter(MyComponent);
export default EnhancedComponent;
```

and getting a warning `Stateless functional components do not support getDerivedStateFromProps.`

Is `withRouter` returning a stateless functional component? I don't really get the meaning of this warning. Would love to get some light here!

The derived state is being updated properly by the way.

Comment: Why are you doing something like this ? for me it doesn't makes any sense. You already have the props why you have to duplicate it in the state?

Comment: That's not supposed to happen. Try `npm ls hoist-non-react-statics`, and make sure all packages that import it are up to date.

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed related to hoisting as mentioned in the comments.
Fixed in react-router 4.3.0-rc.2
https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/6057